# For what B do we have $A^\dagger B+BA=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Suppose A is an arbitrary $n\times n$ matrix over the complex numbers. I am trying to find a nice characterization of the set of $n\times n$ matrices, $V = \{B:A^\dagger B+BA=0\}$.

I know that for the case of projections, $B=pp^\dagger$, this occurs precisely when $p$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with a pure imaginary eigenvalue.  I was hopeful that these projections would span $V$ (which is a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$), but I don't know whether that is true.  Any ideas?

Comment: If A is diagonalizable, then V is spanned by matrices of the form $p q^\dagger$ where both p and q are eigenvectors of $A^\dagger$

Comment: Do you mean all matrices of that form, or do you mean that V is spanned by some subset of matrices of that form.

Comment: I mean that V is spanned by some subset of matrices of this form

Comment: In that case, I guess we would have $V=span\{pq^\dagger:A^\dagger p=\lambda p, A^\dagger q = -\lambda^* q\}$, since that is a necessary condition on the eigenvalues.